# Convert keyboard emoticons into custom png and vice versa

Tags: php, html, unicode, utf, emoticons

Now this is a straight and simple question.

How can I achieve these two things.

**FIRST**

Input -  hey I'm smiling

Output -  `hey I'm smiling <span class ="smile"></span>`

*And vice versa.*

**SECOND**

Input -  hey I'm smiling :smile:

Output - hey I'm smiling

Now I know the words extraction part.  I just don't know in *what form keyboard emoticons are*?

**For First.**

I know this can be achieved by checking each word and using switch-case to check.  But what goes inside the `case` statements?

**For second**

This one has same problem I can use `:smile:` in switch-case. But what should I replace the `:smile:` with to get the keyboard emoticon?

I know this has to do with some unicode characters but since I wasn't sure I came here in a hope for solution.

**P. S** -  *I am using php in server side.*

Comment: Well, this is about string replacement in both directions. PHP offers a normal function for this and one based on regular expressions. Take a look at their documentation, they come with good examples.

Comment: Why do you need the second functionality? It's easier to always keep the original string and only convert smilies to HTML as needed.

Comment: I figured out second.  What about first I still can't solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

First:

```
<?php
$string = "hey I'm smiling ";
echo str_replace("", "<span class =\"smile\"></span>", $string);
?>
```

Second:

```
<?php
$string = "hey I'm smiling :smile:";
echo str_replace(":smile:", "", $string);
?>
```

Comment: I know that part but the emoticon you passed in str_replace I can't find it in my physical keyboard.

Comment: Look here: http://unicode-table.com/en/1F601/.
It should be alt+128513, but it's another smile:  ☺.
Would not it be easier to use this emoticon: _**:)**_?

Comment: It's not colored in desktop Chrome? I am getting a B/W smiley why?

Comment: It's another font. In for example Android they are colored.

Comment: Can those in android be used in desktop Chrome?

Comment: If I'm using the shortcut you told me I'm getting a b/W smiley.  How can I get colored smiley?

Comment: You must use different font. In the Android Emoji font they are colored. In normal fonts they black and white. ☺

Comment: your answer works for only one emoticon.  But if I have an array of emoticon then the above str_replace()  is of no use as I don't want to use hundreds of str_replace()  for each emoticon.  I have raised another question more clear.  You might want to look at that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34551802/convert-emoji-into-custom-images

Comment: Use foreach() function

Comment: I thought about that but will using too many str_replace have any performance issues?

Comment: I'm going to answer your question. You want have for example :) to span ID smiling, or :( to span ID another and give images to spans via css?

Comment: I'm going to have  to span ID SMILE and  to span ID CRY.  :)  and :( are easy to replace using strtr()  but those unicode utf does not support strtr.  You can check that out.