# Convert emoji into custom images

Tags: php, string, utf-8, utf, emoticons

Input -  hey I'm smiling

Output -  hey I'm smiling `<span class ="smile"></span>`

Code

```
$emoticons = array('' =>'<span class ="smile"></span>') ;
$str = strtr($str, $emoticons) ;
```

I can't use `str_replace` because I have more than one element in `$emoticons` array.

This above code is not working the input and output remains same.

Comment: Is your input string UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: What?  I ain't Sure.  It's taken from mysql database.

Comment: You have to ensure that the encoding of your input matches the encoding used in your source code.

Comment: Not only is this a slight variation of the OP's other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34549007/convert-keyboard-emoticons-into-custom-png-and-vice-versa but there was never a problem in the first place. Also, the same user resolved both questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<?php
$str = "hey I'm smiling  and I'm crying  "; // input
$emoticons = array('' =>'<span class="smile"></span>','' =>'<span class="cry"></span>') ; // array of emoticons and spans
$output = strtr($str, $emoticons); // change emoticons from array to spans from array
echo $output; // print it
?>
```

Comment: It's working now!  It wasn't last day when I posted this question.  Weird.